# Why doesn't JavaScript function get called?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I am trying to call my JS function from asp.net code behind but it doesn't work.

```
 protected void btnSavePrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    try
    {
        //int FormTesting;

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        GetType(),
        "MyKey",
        "myFunction();",
        true);

        TestFormNo = ClsTender.InsertAppliedWorks(NitNo, WorkNo, out formno, ContractorID, 
                     Cost.ToDecimal(), bp.LoginMainOfficeID, bp.LoginOrganizationID);
    }
```

and my jsb function which is in .aspx

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
            window.print();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "YourTitle", 
        "myFunction();", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are registering the javascript call on click of button that will be called on next load. Instead of registering call to myFunction() in btnSavePrint_Click code behind event. Bind event on in btnSavePrint in Page_Load. Also make sure definition of myFunction exists.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSavePrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "myFunction();");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. See if it works. You might need to import `System.Web.UI.Control`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(Page), UniqueID, "myFunction()", True)
```

But this code will only register JavaScript function to the browser. As JavaScript is Client-Side Language, it will be registered with this code. Again you have to call this function with some event like

```
 btnSavePrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "myFunction();");
```